# Calculating a rolling return

Tags: r, time-series, cumulative-sum

I have a data frame with 3 columns. What I want to do is to calculate the product of the return over a selected month rolling period for each monthly period (or said another way, each row) (where available). This is the basic structure of the data.

```
set.seed = 100
assets <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
FileDate <- seq(as.Date("2011-12-30"), as.Date("2019-01-31"), by="months")
df <- merge(x = assets, y = FileDate, all.x = TRUE)
df$return <- runif(774, min=0, max=1)
```

What it should end with is a dataframe where a new column is added with the selected period cumulative return for that time frame. For example, I have shown below a four month return. The calculation of the 4-month return on 03/30/2012 from the data would be:
((1+0.81/100)*(1+0.715/100)*(1+0.27/100)*(1+0.80/100)-1)*100

This would be repeated for each value under the X column.

[image]

Comment: Please `set.seed` to reproduce random data and show with sample data what you mean by *month return*.

Comment: I tried to add clarity. Thanks for looking at it. First time, so setting up the question took some attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up utilizing the mutate function there you can set the lag width. in the end version I wanted

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(zoo)

    # Create Test Dataframe
    set.seed = 100
    assets <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
    FileDate <- seq(as.Date("2011-12-30"), as.Date("2019-01-31"), by="months")
    df <- merge(x = assets, y = FileDate, all.x = TRUE)
    df$performance <- runif(774, min=0, max=1)
```

This particular code creates a 5 month average on a rolling basis. If you sort by column X you can see and recreate it in excel.

```
    df <- df %>% 
          group_by(x) %>% 
          mutate(x_mean = rollmean(performance, 5, fill = NA, align = 'right'))
```

I also found a way to create a lag so I could take the 4 prior values to the observation and calculate the mean:

```
    df2 = df %>%
          mutate(perf.4.previous = rollapply(data = perf.1.previous, width = 4, FUN = 
    mean, align = "right", fill = NA, na.rm = T))
```